# TSQL - Select Latest Date by 2 Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need select data in SQL Server.
I have a Data example like this

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE (ID int, SubId int, Createdate DateTime)

INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES (1, 1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (2, 1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (3, 1, '10/27/2020')
                         , (4, 2, '10/21/2020')
                         , (5, 2, '10/21/2020')
                         , (6, 1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (7, 2, '10/23/2020')
                         , (8, 2, '10/22/2020')
                         , (9, 1, '10/25/2020')
                         , (10, 3, '10/21/2020')
```

I want to get 4 records (in table will have a lot of SubId)
2 records latest date by SubId = 1
2 records latest date by SubId = 2
Following example, I expect Select with like table Output

```
DECLARE @tblOutput Table (ID int, SubId int, Createdate DateTime)

INSERT INTO @tblOutput VALUES (3, 1, '10/27/2020')
                        , (9, 1, '10/25/2020')
                        , (7, 2, '10/23/2020')
                        , (8, 2, '10/22/2020')
```

[image: Example] "tooltip"

I try with Union but It's only Order after Union. It's not the result I want.

Please, Help me to select this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Row_Number()` function as shown below:

```
Create table tblA  (ID int, SubId int, Createdate DateTime)

Insert Into tblA values   (1,  1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (2, 1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (3, 1, '10/27/2020')
                         , (4, 2, '10/21/2020')
                         , (5, 2, '10/21/2020')
                         , (6, 1, '10/21/2020')
                         , (7, 2, '10/23/2020')
                         , (8, 2, '10/22/2020')
                         , (9, 1, '10/25/2020')
                         , (10, 3, '10/21/2020')
select Id
 , SubId
 , Createdate
from(
  select *
     , Row_Number() Over (Partition By SubId order by Createdate desc) as RNo
  from tblA
)temp where RNo <= 2 and SubId in (1, 2)
Order by SubId
```

[**Live db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b0a6b48fe12e86331da6fe2e30f8af4)